# Value not passing to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass a value from a child component to the parent component through props, with a function in it but it throws an error `undefined is not a function(evaluating(this.setstate({search: val}))` Please what I am doing wrong

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  do() {
    this.props.value("books");
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.do();
  }
  render() {
    return <Text>yams</Text>;
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };
  con(val) {
    this.setState({ search: val });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child value={this.con} />
        <Text>{this.state.search}</Text>{" "}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `.bind` your function to use `this`. Do it either in your constructor or use an arrow function instead.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        search: ''
    }
    this.con = this.con.bind(this);
}
```

or

```
con = val =>
    this.setState({search: val});
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the `con` function as a fat arrow function:

```
con = (val) => {
    this.setState({search: val});
}
```

This binds `this` to the parents class context